# python which is better and faster? data wrangling in SQL first OR in pandas later?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, date, data-analysis

Usually, for me, loading data from the SQL database on a Server first, then manipulatting later with pandas on my computer.

However, many other's aere preprocessing some data in SQL first (like `case` etc.) then the rest with pandas.

So i wonder which is better and why? thx!

Comment: Depends on the specifics.

Comment: @juergend Could you please offer a brief introduction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is quit general. For a more specific answer, we would need to know more about your setup.

I make some assumptions to answer your question: I assume your database is running on a server and your python code is executed on your local machine.

In this case, you have to consider at least two things:

- transmitted data over the network
- data processing

If you make a general SQL request, large amounts of data are transmitted over the network. Next, your machine has to process the data. Your local machine might be less powerful than the server.

On the other hand, if you submit a specific SQL request, the powerful server can process the data and only return the data you are actually interested.

SQL queries can get long and hard to understand since you have to pass it as one statement. In python, you have the possibility to process the data over multiple lines of code.